# How to replace text under headings in batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have following text in a file

```
DBNAMEAPP=test_app

DBNAMESYS=test_sys
```

I want to replace `test_app` with a value like `mytest_app` and `test_sys` with `mytest_sys`. so the final contents of the file should look like

```
DBNAMEAPP=mytest_app

DBNAMESYS=mytest_sys
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the script can be simplify, but it won't output the "NEW LINE" between each texts.

```
@echo off

set "source=c:\users\microsoft\desktop\text.txt"
set "target=c:\users\microsoft\desktop\text2.txt"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do (
        set "line=%%b"
        if defined line set "line=!line:test=mytest!"
        echo(!line!
    )
) > !target!
Endlocal
del %source% & ren %target% text.txt
pause >nul
```